# Java Buffer connecting files

Tags: java

is it really possible to connect to a file without using a buffer?
I am really confused on this. Any help in clarification would be great.

Comment: Reading byte-by-byte is the same as using a 1-byte-wide buffer... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can read one byte at a time.  Using a buffer is purely for performance.  Not using a buffer can be 10 - 100x slower which is the reason it is typically used.

Note: you can use buffers without complicating your code. i.e. its a just a feature turned on.

Comment: *you can sue buffers without complicating your code*... Can I really sue a Buffer?! :) +1 for the rest though

Comment: There is a `ByteBuffer` which you have to use for NIO, but for IO you can use BuffuredInputStream, BufferedReader, your own byte[], a ByteBuffer or just read one byte at a time.

Comment: "sue" can mean to woo or court, but it was just a typo. ;)

Comment: +1 LOL... they really need you on [English - StackExchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/) site too ;)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp They would have to be desperate. ;)